# How to tell server its 404 error for querystring value in ASP

Tags: http, server, http-status-code-404

I have an eCommerce site in classic asp. On product detail page (product.asp), if the `Product_ID` value is not found in the database, the asp script displays a 404 Product not found error message for customers. But the google crawl error page mentioned following:

```
The target URL doesn't exist, but your server is not returning a 404 (file not found) error
```

My question is how to tell the server it's `404 error` if specific `product_id` is not found in DB. The page will not automatically go to custom `404` page as the product.asp is there but the `product_id` value is not found.

Comment: Hi Babar, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you investigated to find out, if not 404, what error _is_ being returned by your site to google crawler?

Comment: I think crawler just reads the page where 404 not found mentioned, and it can not verify that on server level.

Comment: Hello again Babar; it's good to add more explanation to your question, but the best way to do it is to edit the question itself; that way, any reader can understand everything about the entire problem, all in one place, without having to also read through the comments.

Comment: Response.Status = "404 Not Found" may solve the problem, will check.